# Compare DatetimeField with datetime.now()

Tags: python, datetime, orm, peewee

so i'm using peewee orm for this project ,

i want to compare a date from sqlite database with curent date :

```
class game(BaseModel):
    stuff= CharField()
    stuff2= CharField()
    created_at = DateField()
s=game.select().where(game.created_at==datetime.now().date())
```

but i can't get it to work , and i'm just getting None as result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is query a range of dates:

```
game.select().where(game.created_at.between(
    datetime.date.today(),
    datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

Comment: Thanks , it makes sense now :D
Good ORM by thea , and great work !

Answer (score 3):

You can use peewee's SQL function support:

```
from peewee import fn

game.select().where(game.created_at == fn.now())
```